# how can we write the program by using multiprocessing module of Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import os, codecs, re, string, mysql
import mysql.connector

'''Reading files with txt extension'''
y_ = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
            for lines in x_.readlines():
                y_ = y_ + lines
#print(tokenized_docs) 

'''Tokenizing sentences of the text files'''

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing stop words'''

stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in tokenized_docs[0]:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)

''' Removing punctuation marks'''

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) #see documentation here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html
nw = []
for review in stopword_removed_sentences:
    new_review = ''
    for token in review: 
        new_token = regex.sub(u'', token)
        if not new_token == u'':
            new_review += new_token
    nw.append(new_review)

'''Lowercasing letters after removing puctuation marks.'''

lw = []  #lw stands for lowercase word.
for i in nw:
    k = i.lower()
    lw.append(k) 

'''Removing number with a dummy symbol'''
nr = []
for j in lw:
    string = j
    regex = r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])'
# let "#" be the dummy symbol
    output = re.sub(regex,'#',string)
    nr.append(output)
nrfinal = []    
for j in nr:
    rem = 0
    outr = ''
    for i in j:
        if ord(i)>= 48 and ord(i)<=57:
            rem += 1
            if rem == 1:
                outr = outr+ '#'
        else:
             rem = 0             
             outr = outr+i
    nrfinal.append(outr)

'''Inserting into database'''
def connect():
    for j in nrfinal:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

I am not getting any error with this code. It is doing well for the text files. The problem is only the execution time as I have a lot of text files (nearly 6Gb) for which the program is taking too much time. On inspection i found that it is CPU-bound. So to solve it, multiprocessing is needed. Please help me to write my code with multiprocessing module so that parallel processing can be done.
    Thank you all.

Comment: Before you use multi-processing--- refactor your code looking weaknesses.

Comment: Since the code works, post on   http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Merlin the OP is asking about code not yet written, hence it is off topic on CR

Answer (score 1):

there's an example in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) which demonstrates the use of `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
       print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

You can use this to adapt your code. Once you've obtained the text files, you use the `map` function to execute the rest in parallel. You'd have to define a function encapsulating the code you want to execute on multiple cores.

However, reading files in parallel may decrease the performance. Also, adding content to the database in asynchronously may not work. So you may want to perform these two tasks in the main thread, still